# Cannot get the file list in SoftLayer's Object Storage

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

We operate SoftLayer's Object Storage with this Java library.
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-java/tree/master/sl-objectstorage
「sl-objectstorage.jar」
「com.softlayer.objectstorage.Account」-「search」method

When we would like to get the file list in the container, we can get the file list which is uploaded and saved before 1st Dec 2016 but we cannot get the file list which is saved after 1st Dec 2016 at all.

Do you have any resolution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is an issue with **search** method in some **datacenters**. e.g: ams01.

We are reporting the issue, but it should be good to open a ticket to track this (Attach this forum). Anyway if there will be a fix, we will let you know any news in this thread.

---

> **Updated**

It can be a workaround:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, EncoderException {

        /**
         * Define Object Storage Account information
         */
        String baseUrl = "https://tok02.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/";
        String user = "set me";
        String password = "set me";
        Account account = new Account(baseUrl, user, password);
        // Define your container's name
        String containerName = "r";

        List<Container> containers = account.listAllContainers();
        for (Container container: containers){
            if(container.getName().contains(containerName))
            {
                System.out.println("Container: " + container.getName());
                for(ObjectFile file : container.listObjectFiles())
                {
                    System.out.println("File Name: " + file.getName());
                    System.out.println("Bytes: " + file.getBytes());
                    System.out.println("Meta Tags: " + file.getMetaTags());
                }
                System.out.println("==================================");
            }
        }
     }
```

Also, you can change this line:

> ```
>             if(container.getName().contains(containerName))
> ```

to:

> ```
>             if(container.getName().equal(containerName))
> ```

To get an exact match for the container name

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Do you know any issue of "search" method also for tok02? In such a case, what is the typical workaround?

Comment: As the test, these are the locations that have this issue:

**ams01, par01, sao01, tok02**

let me check for a workaround

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I would be very appreciated if you cloud do so. I will wait for your new comment.

Comment: Please, review the **Updated** section in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, Ruber. I will try and be back.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best if you could open a SoftLayer (IBM BlueMix) support ticket, including the data center, container name, and if possible, times when the queries were made and what the expected results were.

The support staff can then correlate it with any known issues and resolutions.

Comment: Honestly I was told to ask at StackOverflow by SoftLayer support.  Do you have any resolution?